# Customize Source-Info on MailChimp List

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

My application creates members in a mailchimp list. It uses the mailchimp REST API.

The table on the mailchimp web page, showing all member of a list, has a column "Source". I would like to see the name of my application in this column instead  "API - Generic".

Is it possible to customize that?

Thanks,
Claus